# Common Lisp dotimes result mystery

Tags: loops, common-lisp

I got this

```
(dotimes (temp-one 10 temp-one))
```

from the Hyperspec examples on `dotimes`. Running this produces the answer 10. So the `temp-one` in the third parameter position is acting as a returned "result," but how did it get to 10 when `dotimes` starts at 0 and would only go to 9?

```
>(dotimes (temp-one 10 temp-one) (format t "~3d " temp-one))
  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9 
10
```

What am I missing here about the third parameter?

Comment: As the [hyperspec says](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_dotime.htm#dotimes): "At the time result-form is processed, var is bound to the number of times the body was executed"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the [**dotimes** Hyperspec entry](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_dotime.htm) it states it's a **macro** meaning you get to see "under the hood" by calling **macroexpand**:

```
(macroexpand '(dotimes (i 10 i)))
```

SBCL:

```
(BLOCK NIL
  (LET ((I 0))
    (DECLARE (TYPE UNSIGNED-BYTE I))
    (TAGBODY
      (GO #:G386)
     #:G385
      (TAGBODY)
      (PSETQ I (1+ I))
     #:G386
      (UNLESS (>= I 10) (GO #:G385))
      (RETURN-FROM NIL (PROGN I)))))
```

Allegro CL:

```
(do ((i 0 (1+ i)))
    ((>= i 10) i))
```

In both cases the iteration variable **i** is increased by one, and then the end test `(>= i 10)` is done. As [jkiiski](http://#comment93686735_53405744) wrote:

> "At the time *result-form* is processed, *var* is bound to the number of times the body was executed."

and the `(return-from ..)` form (SBCL) and `i` form (Allegro CL) are evaluated after the variable increase and test.

Comment: Right after I posted this I realized it had to be something like the last iteration is sent to `result-form` even though it fails/terminates. BTW, what sort of Lisp is that in the SBCL expanded macro? I'm still just a beginner and haven't seen much yet.

Comment: The macroexpansion given by SBCL, the `(BLOCK NIL ..`), is also Common Lisp. It's in upper case as that is the standard. (My Allegro example was done in its "Modern" mode that keeps case and uses lowercase for the standard functions; it also comes with "ANSI" mode that behaves like SBCL). Coding using `tagbody` with `go` and labels feels like low-level assembly code, usually you would use higher-level abstractions, but nevertheless it's all part of Common Lisp.

Answer (score 4):

Hyperspec says:

> At the time result-form is processed, var is bound to the number of
>   times the body was executed.

So, in the third form, the result-form, the variable gets first bound to the number of times the body was executed first, and then the third form is evaluated.

That is why the value of the variable is `10` and not the current value `9`.

This is also visible, if you do

```
(macroexpand-1 '(dotimes (temp-one 3 temp-one) (format t "~3d~%" temp-one)))

;; resulting in CLISP in:
;; (DO ((TEMP-ONE 0 (1+ TEMP-ONE))) ((>= TEMP-ONE 10) TEMP-ONE)
;;  (FORMAT T "~3d~%" TEMP-ONE)) ;
;; T
```

So finally, `(1+ TEMP-ONE)` is returned by the `DO` loop, to which `DOTIMES` expands to - as pointed out by @zut.